# Switch cursor to another window between more than 2 windows

Tags: window

I could use `C-x o` to switch buffer properly between two windows,
but when it comes to more than two windows, it fails

[image]

The cursor stay instantly on the current window.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: There must be something odd with your setup, I think. `C-x o` doesn't stop working for me, anyway, with more than two windows in a frame. I tried it out with the configuration shown, and it still works.

Comment: Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Otherwise, consider `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are `windmove-right` `windmove-down` and so on..
These can be bind individually,  but I find that it's not the most convenient way to navigate around. ( a solution is presented here: http://emacsblog.org/2008/05/01/quick-tip-easier-window-switching-in-emacs/ )

Additionally there are a few packages that help navigation in very creative ways:

`ace-window` 
https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window

You assign a binding for `ace-window` and when it is called a character from the home line (i.e "asdf...") appears in the top left of the window, typing that character will navigate the cursor there. There is some added functionality for swaping and deleting windows as well.

Similarly, There's `switch-window` https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window

And `win-switch` That is explained clearly here: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~genovese/emacs/win-switch/